# Can PS5 use HDCP DRM in games?

Tags: drm, ps5

I intend to connect using a HDMI splitter with a projector and/or television and haven't made any effort to ensure that my chain of devices is HDCP-compatible. Since my usage will be purely gaming-related I was planning to disable the HDCP in the system settings, but the explanation explicitly states that some *games* won't work (the screenshot isn't mine, I don't own the console yet):

[image: screenshot]

I initially assumed that HDCP is only used with DRM'd streaming services — can games freely use HDCP as well?

Answer (score 3):

From the PS5's perspective, it seems the only applications that would be disabled are what you said.  [Applications such as Hulu and Netflix](https://stealthoptional.com/how-to/what-is-hdcp-ps5-should-i-disable-hdcp-does-hdcp-affect-games/) for example won't work with this setting disabled for obvious reasons.  This is probably a poor choice of words to display as the warning message.

> The PS5 is much more than a gaming machine; it gives you access to a wide range of media apps, such as Netflix, Hulu, Amazon Prime, and Disney Plus. There is an obvious problem if you were able to record video on the PS5 while accessing any of these apps. So that’s the reason HDCP exists on your PS5.

As far as games making use of [HDCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-bandwidth_Digital_Content_Protection), I would think it is not possible, or at the very least, an unnecessary extra step for video game makers to do.  The game itself (or rather its manufacturer) would need to obtain a license to use the patent, which doesn't really make sense, since it is not a device (it is the content itself).

> In order to make a **device** that plays HDCP-enabled content, the manufacturer must obtain a license for the patent from Intel subsidiary Digital Content Protection LLC, pay an annual fee, and submit to various conditions

HDCP is meant to be licensed at the *device* level (in this case, Sony licenses HDCP for use in the Playstation 5s they manufacture).

Comment: Do you imply that the game publishers/developers would have to HDCP-certify each title? The streaming services are presumably individually licensed, I don't know if you imply that games by their nature can't (or that this wouldn't be sensible).

Comment: @user598527 What I mean is the game developers would need to acquire a license to use HDCP, and then subsequently somehow encode the games to be HDCP encrypted (which I don't even know if that is possible or not).  Even if it is, it would seem to me to be an unnecessary step for game developers to under take, since from what I understand, it is devices that need to implement HDCP and the manufacture of said device needs to be licensed to use it.

Comment: Replace "Game Developer" with "Netflix".  I wouldn't expect Netflix to have an HDCP license.  They do however require that whatever device _uses_ Netflix be HDCP compliant (the PS5 in this case), to protect the content from being copied.

Comment: I see your point now. I agree that HDCP-encryption doesn't seem sensible since close to no publishers oppose streaming and uploading VODs and it'd likely complicate multi-platform releases heavily — if real-time game content can be encrypted in the first place. Sony's wording is odd, I wonder if there are games which display video from (HDCP-supported) streaming services or have DRM'd some pre-recorded video of their own.